# passing java variable to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I will need to pass a java variable to a javascript function. I have my codes as below. Wondering is that the correct way?

Because I have some problem here when the page first load, and the button is clicked, the chartData and categories is empty.

I am expecting the below:

```
chartData = [{"name":"Anne","data":[1.0,0.0,4.0]},
             {"name":"Billy","data":[5.0,7.0,10000.0]}]
categories = ["APPLES","BANANAS","ORANGES"]

public String doLoadChartDataAction () {

    String _cat = "[{\"name\":\"Anne\",\"data\":[1.0,0.0,4.0]},{\"name\":\"Billy\",\"data\":[5.0,7.0,10000.0]}]";
    String _data = "[\"APPLES\",\"BANANAS\",\"ORANGES\"]";

    System.out.println("1.0 " + " _cat:" + _cat);
    System.out.println("1.0 " + " _data:" + _data);

    setCategories(_cat);
    setChartData(_data);

    return "";      
}


 <p:commandButton styleClass="commandButton" value="This" id="btnThis" action="#{pc_Test.doLoadChartDataAction}" 
    oncomplete="renderChart('container','line','Sample Chart','${pc_Test.chartData}', '${pc_Test.categories}');">   
 </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: I think when you load the page, you can do an ajax call to your server side, then the server(java) returns the data you want; in your javascript, you can use the data for processing. i.e. the java file returns you an json object and callback processing use the json object..

Comment: @Robin is correct do you want an json Object form java and then process in javascript

Comment: @Robin Thanks for your comments. I manage to fix this with the below amended codes. (:

Comment: @BholaVishwakarma Thanks for your comments. I manage to fix this with the below amended codes. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String doLoadChartDataAction () {

String _cat = "[{\"name\":\"Anne\",\"data\":[1.0,0.0,4.0]},{\"name\":\"Billy\",\"data\":[5.0,7.0,10000.0]}]";
String _data = "[\"APPLES\",\"BANANAS\",\"ORANGES\"]";

System.out.println("1.0 " + " _cat:" + _cat);
System.out.println("1.0 " + " _data:" + _data);

//setCategories(_cat);
//setChartData(_data);

RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.addCallbackParam("chartData", _data);
context.addCallbackParam("categories", _cat);

return "";      
}

<p:commandButton styleClass="commandButton" value="This" id="btnThis" action="#{pc_Test.doLoadChartDataAction}" 
oncomplete="renderChart('container','line','Sample Chart', args.chartData, args.categories);">
```